# Como abrir um arquivo .sql no pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, ciência-de-dados

Pretendo fazer um dataframe de um banco de dados que importei do pgadmin4 como um arquivo 'vialactea.sql' quando tento executar o comando do pandas no jupyter só da mensagem de erro.

O banco esta salvo na mesma pasta que o arquivo do notebook, o que facilita o acesso ao mesmo.

```
vialactea = pandas.read_sql('vialactea.sql')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-376ba7310a4f> in <module>
----> 1 vialactea = pandas.read_sql('vialactea.sql')

NameError: read_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'
```

Comment: Esse comando é para vc ler a partir de um banco de dados, por isso ele exige a conexao (`required positional argument: 'con'`), [veja a documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('teste.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# inserindo dados na tabela
cursor.execute("select * from banco")
```